# Powerbuilder 12.6 connection to a SQL Server linked server

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder

Do you know how to set SQLCA connection parameters in order to connect my pb 12.6 app to a linked server on SQL Server 2012?

We already connect to a SQL Server database but we also need to connect to a linked server on this database (customer requirement)

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linked server happens at the server side. No change to login. To access the tables you will need to use the link name and database name in sql. To make it easier I would create views in your database that refer to the linked database table. Then you can use the view name in your app.